# Kendo UI Grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a JSON data structure that I need to bind to [Kendo UI grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular) . The data is something like below.There will be no header fields / columns.I believe kendo UI expects columnns not sure *how to bind data to grid without column headers*? I see lot of examples with column headers but could not find any without headers.Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
["1 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
 "2 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
 "3 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
 "4 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
 "5 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
 "6 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do you expect the grid to look? A Kendo DataSource requires an array of Objects, and you have an array of Strings. http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-support-for-data-in-array-form-instead-of-object-form

Comment: You need to parse and reformat your JSON data. You need column headers for kendogrid, there is no way around that (although you can hide them after the fact).

Comment: Thank you both.Based on your inputs this is my understanding to achieve my requirement 1)To bind data to grid the datasource requires array of objects  2) I must have column headers but  can hide them. Can you guys correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes, refer to this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/local-data-binding), this is an example of an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the data in order to make it suitable for the Kendo `dataSource` as follows:

```
var dataArr = ["1 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
                   "2 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
                   "3 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
                   "4 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
                   "5 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999",
                   "6 ABCDEFGHIJKL 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"];


var formattedData = [];
$.each(dataArr, function(index, value) {
    formattedData.push({value});  
});
```

Once you have this `formattedData`, you can initialise the `dataSource` and associated `kendoGrid`:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: formattedData
});
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    autoBind: true,
    dataSource: dataSource
});
```

And finally, you can hide the column header as per your requirement, using the following:

```
$(".k-grid .k-grid-header").hide();
```

Or optionally, using CSS:

```
.k-grid .k-header {
   display: none;
}
```

I have made a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ideFu/5) to demonstrate the above.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sandman.Just one question what is the purpose of formattedData function?